# Can you run a version of vscode inside the browser without a server?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ace-editor, monaco-editor

Is there any way to run a version of VS Code inside a browser without a server? (inside a React or Angular app). Something like an enhanced version of the monaco editor.

Of course that means it will have some missing functionalities.

If not, are there any other options?

Comment: what do you mean "without a server"? For there to be no server, you'd basically have to be using the file protocol, and access to local filesystem contents would be severely limited. I'm not sure if VS Code's architecture is designed for such a use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I could find, it is possible to run VSCode in the browser (since we have `vscode.dev`), but there doesn't seem to be anyway to deploy it yourself yet?

This [Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/135856) is probably what you want, but there isn't any information there (or on the repo) yet.

It does strongly suggest that https://github.com/microsoft/vscode is the version used for `vscode.dev`, so there might be things to be found there, until official instructions/embedding is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Try this https://securingsincity.github.io/react-ace/
its something of the same king what you want

Answer (score 1):

You can possibly use Gitpod self-host, https://github.com/gitpod-io/gitpod or https://github.com/gitpod-io/openvscode-server they both have documentation on how to create your own version of VSCode for the web, however, as I've never tried to create one myself, I don't know if it accomplishes your specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how you treat vscode.
if it is just a editor software, there'll be a lot of .
For you customerization purpose, it sounds something like 'https://github.com/cdr/code-server'

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps, but you can try looking up gitpod.io. It opens up a visual studio code instance on your browser with options of installing extensions as well.
Use the link like gitpod.io/#https://github.com/username/repo-name

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).